# How to make navbar stick to the top of the page, after an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make the navbar stick to the top of the page after the header has been scrolled by.

So it would be something similar to this, [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn), but with a picture. So with the picture, it would be stretched to across most of the screen, but it also adjusts depending on how big the window is. Therefore I can't just say after 200px, make the navbar stick, because the image would vary in size. If possible, is there a way to make a Javascript function that will register for once getting to the bottom of any element, the navbar will stick?

HTML:

```
    <header>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Mount_Shuksan,_Picture_Lake_(2362739742).jpg" alt="">
  </header>

  <nav id = "nav_bar">
      <ul class = "navbar-list">
          <li>
              <a href="">link1</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropbtn">link2</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-content">
                      <a href="#">link 1</a>
                      <a href="#">link 2</a>
                      <a href="#">link 3</a>
                      <a href="">link 4</a>
                  </div>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="">link 3</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="">link4</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </nav>

<body>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

CSS:

```
body{
margin:0px;
}

header{
margin: 0 auto;
/*position: fixed;*/
top: 0;
}


img{
max-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
top: 0;
display: block;
}

.navbar-fixed {
top: 0;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
}


ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
}

li {
float: left;
} 

li a, .dropbtn {
display: inline-block;
color: white;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: red;
 }

li.dropdown {
display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: green;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
```

[codepen.io](http://codepen.io/DeadCatLady/pen/BQZjqm) -- include a sample image

Comment: Whats wrong with the codepen?  That seems to do what your after, what am I missing?

Comment: In my code pen, the one at the bottom of the post, the navbar doesn't stick to the top of the page after the image has been scrolled past.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```js
var nav_bar_top_offset = $('#nav_bar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > nav_bar_top_offset) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    $('#nav_bar').removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 0;
}
section{background:#fff}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.fixed{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Mount_Shuksan,_Picture_Lake_(2362739742).jpg" alt="">
  </header>

<nav id="nav_bar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">link2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        <a href="#">link 2</a>
        <a href="#">link 3</a>
        <a href="">link 4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

 <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: First off, thank you for taking the time to do this. But I was wondering if there would there be a way to do this without making the image in the background? Like just have the image above the navbar, the nav bar will "affix" to the top.

Comment: This is obviously a copy of my answer.

Comment: @Ionut Why would I copy your answer? initially my answer was different, but after updating as per CatTreats's requirement it just looks similar like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Like you used the Tutorial Codepen, just change the selectors of the example to your selectors.

Try this:

```
var  mn = $("#nav_bar");
    mns = "navbar-fixed";
    hdr = $('header').height();

$(window).scroll(function() {
  if( $(this).scrollTop() > hdr ) {
    mn.addClass(mns);
  } else {
    mn.removeClass(mns);
  }
});
```

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YpQqpx)

---

**Remember**:  If you set your navbar to sticky, the space where the navbar was will be removed. So it could happen that your navbar will be over your first line of text. Just add to your header a padding of the height of your navbar. This can be done in your js too.

Either you add a class with this padding or you add it manually. Here are the examples:

```
$('header').addClass("extraPadding"); // extraPadding is the class that you have to create
```

or

```
$('header').css("padding-bottom", "40"); // 40 could be the height of your navbar
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is this. Hope will help you. Hit on the `Run code snippet` to see it in action.

First you check when you reach the element you want to stay fixed while scrolling and add the `fixed` class, and then if you scroll back you remove it.

```js
var navBarOffset = $('#nav_bar').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function() {
  var navBar= $('#nav_bar');
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= navBarOffset ) {
    navBar.addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    navBar.removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  top: 0;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  width: 100%; 
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}
.navbar-fixed {
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Mount_Shuksan,_Picture_Lake_(2362739742).jpg" alt="">
</header>

<nav id="nav_bar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
    <li>
      <a href="">link1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropbtn">link2</a>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">link 1</a>
        <a href="#">link 2</a>
        <a href="#">link 3</a>
        <a href="">link 4</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">link4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>


</body>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var nav = $('.adjustlink');
    var pos = nav.offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function (){
        var fix = ($(this).scrollTop() > pos) ? true : false;
        nav.toggleClass("fix-nav", fix);
    });
```

hope this one help you [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bLjwn4a/)

Comment: is it helpfull for you?